# What does MAX_MODULE_NAME32 do?

Tags: c++

Hey so I've been reading a book recently and i saw this line of code:

```
TCHAR procName[MAX_MODULE_NAME32] = TEXT("sauerbraten.exe");
```

and I'm curious what MAX_MODULE_NAME32 actually does.(I've tried reading documentation but I wasn't able to find any info on what it does.)

Comment: Do a search in your code base.  There should be a line somewhere like `#define MAX_MODULE_NAME32 <some_value>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement declares an array of type `TCHAR` of length `MAX_MODULE_NAME32`.

```
TCHAR procName[MAX_MODULE_NAME32]
```

basically the maximum number of allowable characters in the module name. It is implementation defined but in [this search result](https://tyleo.github.io/sharedlib/doc/winapi/tlhelp32/constant.MAX_MODULE_NAME32.html) I see it is `255` in that particular case, though it may be platform and compiler-setting dependent.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a preprocessor macro, and it was defined inside the "tlhelp32.h" Windows header. Macros are like a variable but they won't use any memory because the preprocessor actually replaces every instance of "MAX_MODULE_NAME32" in your code to the value it was assigned during compilation, and you can't assign a value to it either because it doesn't exist during runtime.

That specific macro tells you what is the maximum number of characters a process module name can have.

If you're using Visual Studio, you can right click the macro and press "Go to definiton" to see where it was defined. Hovering over it should tell you it's assigned value as well.